# Gnupg doesn't decrypt the file in php

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, gnupg

I try to decrypt my enrypted file(zip archive which contains multiple files) with `Gnupg` in php, but it constantly returns false. no exception or error message.
here's encryption:

```
 $gpg = gnupg_init();
 gnupg_seterrormode($gpg, GNUPG_ERROR_EXCEPTION);
 // public key
 $publicKey = file_get_contents('pubkey.pub');
 $key = gnupg_import($gpg, $publicKey);
 gnupg_addencryptkey($gpg, $key['fingerprint']);
 // zip file
 $zip = file_get_contents('myzip.zip');
 $encryptedFile = gnupg_encrypt($gpg, $zip);
 //save encrypted file
 file_put_contents('myzip.zip.gpg', $encryptedFile);
```

here's decryption:

```
$gpg = gnupg_init();

$privateKey = file_get_contents('private.asc');
$key = gnupg_import($gpg, $privateKey);

gnupg_adddecryptkey($gpg, $key['fingerprint'], '12345');
$file = file_get_contents('myzip.zip.gpg');
$content = gnupg_decrypt($gpg, $file); // <- always returns false
```

I tried to decrypt the file with online tool. at first I tried to decrypt only 1 text file and it worked(it displayed the content of file). I tried to decrypt the zip archive as well

[image]

but everytime I try to decrypt it with `gnupg_decrypt` in php it return false. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: php version? key-gen, export steps?

Comment: Does the key contain valid data after the line `$key = gnupg_import($gpg, $privateKey);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `gnupg` version. I instilled `gpg2` and it worked.